# .htaccess probleme ? Not any Css and link working

Tags: css, .htaccess, hyperlink

I'm having a problem with my website, usign a Database,

Not any Css are working, and not any link. .  . .

here is the link of it it: http://lamett.co.ke/

The weird thing is that everythign is workign perfectly on my other hosting, but not in my clien thsoting . . .  I have rewrite the .htacess file but it doenst seem to change anything . .

Here is my .htaccess ( if it's link to this, which I think)

```
#Fix Rewrite
Options -Multiviews


<Files ~ "^.(htaccess|htpasswd)$">
deny from all
</Files>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^admin/.*$ - [PT]
RewriteRule ^css/.*$ - [PT]
RewriteRule ^js/.*$ - [PT]
RewriteRule ^files/.*$ - [PT]
Options -Indexes
<FilesMatch ".(gif|jpg|jpeg|png|ico)$">
Header set Cache-Control "max-age=3600"
</FilesMatch>


RewriteRule ^(\w+)/rss?$ rss.php?lang=$1

RewriteBase /lamett_co_ke/
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/product/(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)?$ index.php?       type=product&category=$2&subcategory=$3&product=$4&lang=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/product/(\w+)/(\w+)?$ index.php?type=product&category=$2&subcategory=$3&lang=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/product/(\w+)?$ index.php?type=product&category=$2&lang=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/project/(\w+)/(\w+)?$ index.php?toptype=project&type=$2&lang=$1&ext=$3
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/project/(\w+)?$ index.php?toptype=project&type=$2&lang=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/page-(\w+)?$ index.php?type=$2&page=$3&lang=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)/(\w+)?$ index.php?toptype=$2&type=$3&lang=$1
RewriteRule ^(\w+)/(\w+)?$ index.php?type=$2&lang=$1


#ErrorDocument 400 ./error/400.html
#ErrorDocument 404 ./error/404.html
DirectoryIndex index.html index.php      
order deny,allow
```

Would really love any help with this, thank you so much !!!

Comment: With `<base href="http://lamett.com.gt/lamett_co_ke/"/>` in your HTML document you’re telling the browser that’s how he should complete the relative paths to your stylesheets to an absolute URL … but the stylesheets don’t seem to be available under those addresses, f.e. `http://lamett.com.gt/lamett_co_ke/style/style.css` only results in a 404. `http://lamett.com.gt/style/style.css` however delivers a stylesheet … same goes for most of your other stylesheets and scripts.

Comment: So throw that `base` element out of your HTML. (Shouldn’t be used in any case, IMHO does more harm than it actually helps – I have never ever had any need to use it.)

Comment: hm, the thing is all the file are in the those links ( http://lamett.com.gt/lamett_co_ke/style/style.css for eg) I ve try to remove it and dint change anything . . .

Comment: I don’t understand what you’re trying to say here.

Comment: I mean the the stylesheet exist on my hosting at: http://lamett.com.gt/lamett_co_ke/style/style.css

I can see the file in my hosting . . . 

I use lamett_co_ke folder as there is another website in lamett.com.gt

lamett_co_ke folder is the folder assign to its domain name . 

Do you have any other recommendation by any chance ? I'm really struggling with this ...

Comment: The structure within the _file_ system of your server and HTTP are two different things; and clearly your stylesheet is _not_ reachable via http://lamett.com.gt/lamett_co_ke/style/style.css, as that only results in a 404. Try and remove all of your rewriting, so we can at least figure out whether accessing the stylesheet via that URL works without it. Apart from that, there’s litte I can do for you here, because I don’t know the internals of your server.

Comment: I got it work . .  was a problem of path in my config.php and DB . . .. 

Thank you for your time :)